# .htaccess permanent redirect and canonicalization

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I want to use .htaccess to permanently redirect all my following links;

- **mysite.com/post/44/my-post-title.html**
- **mysite.com/post/44/**
- **mysite.com/44/**

to;

- **mysite.com/my-post-title.html**

Note: if link doesn't contain the my-post-title.html, i use php script to get the post title from post id i-e- 44 and redirect it to the standard link pattern ( mysite.com/my-post-title.html ).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using `RewriteEngine`.

You need to add following lines to .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule TheTule RedirectionURL [R]
```

Where TheRule is a regular expression that satisfies your condition in this case you can write :

^/post/(0-9)*/$

and the RedirectionURL can be : my-post-title.html

it will look like :

```
RewriteRule ^\/post\/(0-9)*\/$ my-post-title.html [R]
```

You will have to write your own rules.
Do not forget [R] it is used for external HTTP redirection.

Comment: Why search engine is indexing all possible URLs mysite.com/post/44, mysite.com/44, mysite.com/post/44/my-post-title.html, and my site.com/my-post-title.html

Comment: If your talking about Google, then provide them a sitemap of your website so that only those links are indexed. You can do that using Google's webmaster tools. Generate that sitemap dynamically.